# 'adding' two angles

Tags: java, geometry, ardor3d

Alright, so I got two angles. One is the joystick's angle, and the other is the camera to player angle. The camera's angle. Now I want it so when I press up on the joystick it moves the player away from the camera. How  would I do this? And is there a easy way to do it in Java or Ardor3d?

edit: Here is the code of how I get my angles.

```
float camDegree = (float) Math.toDegrees(Math.atan2(
                     _canvas.getCanvasRenderer().getCamera().getLocation().getXf() - colladaNode.getTranslation().getXf(),
                     _canvas.getCanvasRenderer().getCamera().getLocation().getYf()) - colladaNode.getTranslation().getYf());

            player.angle = (float) Math.toDegrees(Math.atan2(padX, padY));
            Quaternion camQ = new Quaternion().fromAngleAxis(camDegree, Vector3.UNIT_Y);
```

Comment: How are your "angles" represented? Are you really working in three dimensions, or just using a 3D API?

Comment: actually I'm just using the X and Z axis so it's only 2d. I'll add a bit of code to the main question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have to say that I don't really understand your question, but it seems to be about how to implement camera-relative control using a joystick.

The most important piece of advice I can give you is that it's better not to compute angles, but to work directly with vectors.

Suppose that the camera is looking in the direction **v** (in some types of game this vector will be pointing directly at the player, but not all types of game, and not always):

[image: the look vector from a camera to a player can be resolved into vertical and horizontal components]

Typically you don't care about the vertical component of this vector, so remove it to get the horizontal component, which I'll call **y** for reasons that will become apparent later:

> **y** = **v** − (**v** · **up**) **up**

where **up** is a unit vector pointing vertically upwards.

We can find the horizontal vector that's perpendicular to **y** using the cross product (and remembering the right hand rule):

> **x** = **v** × **up**

[image: the vectors x and y form a horizontal coordinate basis]

Now you can see that **y** is a vector in the plane pointing forwards (away from the camera), and **x** a vector in the plane pointing right (sideway with respect to the camera). If you normalise these vectors:

> **x̂** = **x** / |**x**|
>
> **ŷ** = **y** / |**y**|

then you can use **x̂** and **ŷ** as the coordinate basis for camera-relative motion of the player. If your joystick readings are *Jx* and *Jy*, then move the player by

> *s* (*Jx* **x̂** + *Jy* **ŷ**)

where *s* is an appropriate scalar value proportional to the player's speed.

(Notice that no angles were computed at any point in this answer!)