# Splitting this into a x and y point?

Tags: java, math, geometry, trigonometry

Alright, so I'm still trying to make my players movements relative to the camera. I got a good answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4321382?tab=votes#tab-top)
But he ends it with: `s(Jx x̂ + Jy ŷ)`

So how can I turn that equation into a x and y?

Comment: Why don't you ask this as a comment on that answer first?

Comment: It looks like all the information you need is in the answer to the previous question ... unless you want someone to write the code for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *s* (*Jx* **x̂** + *Jy* **ŷ**)

is the equation to get a new point. *Jx* and *Jy* are the values from the joystick (x-value and y-value), *s* your speed (the higher, the faster) and **x̂**, **ŷ** are the x- and y-vectors from your coordinate system set by the camera (you have to compute those every time you compute a new movement)

So take these values, use the formula and you'll get a new player coordinate in the normal x/y plane. (iaw, the result is a point with an x and a y component, which are you x and y values)